# Is current video time available using a Video Element for a live stream

Tags: html5-video, webrtc

Using a video element on a subscriber / viewer for a live stream, is it possible to get the running stream time? I know that `ontimeupdate` will give the time (in seconds) at which playback started, but I need the live streams time; the start of publishing instead. The bottom line is that I'd like to know how close to in-sync my publisher and subscriber are.

In my scenario a live publisher has been publishing for 10 minutes and a subscriber connects and starts playing; the subscribers `ontimeupdate` will yield a value around 0.1 or so, which would be 600 seconds behind in my case.

Comment: Have you tried with `currentTime` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime ?

Comment: `currentTime` appears to be the same value passed to `ontimeupdate`; seconds since play start

Comment: I guess if you want to get the actual time difference you'll need to implement some kind of synchronization mechanism.